# Running my first Spider, iterating through data returns None

Tags: python, scrapy, data-extraction

I am writing my first Spider with Scrapy, my goal is to scrape the imdb top 100 movies webpage, get the rating, title, and link of each movie. I am trying to iterate through every movie and store it's values in a dictionary, however when I attempt to iterate through the movies the Spider returns 'none' for each one.

```
    def parse(self, response):
       for movie in response.css('table.chart td'):
           yield {
               'title': movie.css('td.titleColumn a::text').get(),
               'rating': movie.css('td.ratingColumn.imdbRating strong::text').get(),
               'link': movie.css('td.titleColumn a::attr(href)').get(),
           }
```

Could someone explain to me why it's returning None?
When I change movie.css to response.css it returns the requested data for the first movie.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. If you're satisfied with an answer then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your selector is incorrect.

1. `response.css('table.chart td')` will return a list of `Selector` objects.
2. `movie` is a `Selector` object.

When you write `movie.css('td.titleColumn a::text')`, it combines both the selectors which effectively translates to the following:

```
response.css('table.chart td td.titleColumn a::text')
```

Is the selector a valid selector in your specific case?

The [official docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=selectors#selectors) on Selector should be helpful for you.